# Ocaml: warning 40 when usage of tag of a variant type in a simple module

Tags: ocaml

I have a simple module in a text file **mpd.ml** with variants types:

```
type ack_error =
  | Not_list        
  | Arg             
  | Password        
  | Permission      
  | Unknown         
  | No_exist        
  | Playlist_max    
  | System          
  | Playlist_load   
  | Update_already  
  | Player_sync     
  | Exist           

 type response = Ok | Error of (ack_error * int * string * string)
```

And when I use them :

```
let test_ok test_ctxt =  assert_equal Mpd.Ok (Mpd.parse_response "OK\n")
```

Even if everything works, I have those warnings:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -o test -package oUnit,str -linkpkg -g mpd.ml test.ml
File "test.ml", line 7, characters 2-4:
Warning 40: Ok was selected from type Mpd.response.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
File "test.ml", line 8, characters 2-7:
Warning 40: Error was selected from type Mpd.response.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
```

What does it means and how can I improve my code so that those warnings disapear.

** edit **

full code : https://gist.github.com/cedlemo/8806f367a971bacfaa0f59b1c78a3605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that you're showing not the line, that provoked the warning. As in the warning it is said, that the `Ok` constructor is between characters `2-4`, but there is nothing alike in your code.

In general, I would suggest to use IDE, like Emacs, Vim, etc, as they will directly jump to the source of the error.

Since, the warning is quite common, I will still explain the reasoning behind it. In OCaml constructors and field names are identifiers, that as well as any other identifier have a scope, and the scope is the module. So, whenever you define a variant type, you are actually defining several constructors in the scope of the module. To reference to the constructor, you need either to use a fully qualified name, or make sure that it is in the scope. If you're in the module, that defines it, then you're ok, otherwise you need to bring the name to the scope somehow.

In previous version of OCaml it was an error, to use a constructor, that is not in the scope. Just a regular unbound identifier. At the latest, the heuristics was added, that infers from which scope the constructor comes. But it is still guarded by a warning, so people is actually trying not to use it. (Digression, I'm wondering why people added a feature, and then momentary disgraced it with a warning, so no one will actually use it).

So, to fix the warning you need to qualify all constructors with the module name, or, alternatively open the module to bring all definitions to the scope, e.g., `open Mpd`.

### Update

So, the code full code discloses that at the line 7, as indeed was pointed by a compiler there is an unqualified constructor:

```
match response with
| Ok -> false
| Error ...
```

Here the `Ok` is unqualified, the correct way is to say:

```
match response with
| Mpd.Ok -> false
| Mpd.Error ...
```

The general advice, that describes policy that I use in particular, is to define a module that defines only types, so that you can open it rather safely. This will also solve you a problem of repeating type definitions in `.mli` as it is considered acceptable to not to have `.mli` file for a module, that defines only types.

Comment: FYI I use neovim and here I just shown the code that I thought was relevant. You say that I should qualify the contrustor or open the module. But the warning come from the use of `Mpd.Ok`. do You want I display the full code which is not long ?

Comment: Sure, put the whole code, or upload it to the gist. If the constructor is properly qualified, then it will not provoke a warning. On the other hand, the definitions, that you've shown in the file `mpd` might be enclosed in some other module. People, usually make this mistake, by adding a `module Xxx = struct ...` into a file `xxx.ml`, thus putting the definitions into `Xxx.Xxx` module.

Comment: I have added a gist link. You will see there is no nested module. ... And now I see and I am just ashamed . I didn't focus on the good line.

Comment: It is not you, who is ashamed but your IDE :P (Disclaimer, yes I'm a emacser)

Comment: Nop it is me, vim support numbered lines too (I almost flagged your comment for inappropiate content ). thx BTW.